# SQL query for extracting distinct records by getting the last entered row

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL query for extracting last entered number field(if we enter 11 in 3 rows take last row) from a table.Consider the following table

[image: table]

I want to show result like this

[image: result]

Comment: The input and output are identical

Comment: soryy,edited the uestion

Comment: does the table has a timestamp column?

Comment: yes, created date will there

Comment: Can you tag the version of the database please

Comment: you can use this query ````select * from tableName group by no order by created desc;````

Answer (score 1):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY created_date DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT NO, Letter
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The above would return the latest row for every `NO` group.  If instead you want the earliest row, then change the sort order used by `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for you

```
SELECT a.NO,a.Letter FROM yourtable a
JOIN
(SELECT max(date) AS date,NO FROM yourtable GROUP BY NO) b ON a.NO=b.NO AND a.DATE=b.DATE
ORDER BY a.NO
```